# How to use property of class in loop?

Tags: angular, loops

I want to have a loop with some properties of a class, not all of it's properties.
I want to implement a function for properties of the class. But even I don't know how to set the length of loop with number of properties in class.
For example this is my class:

```
class Address{
id: number,
street: string,
state: string,
}
```

and I want to make a loop with length of the object of this class and do something on each property of this object of Address class, something like this:

```
for (let i; i< /*length of address object*/; i++) {
  if (/*each property of address */) {
   // do sth
  }
}
```

I'm using Angular 4.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure what you want to achieve, but 
you could create a new list, which contains objects of the properties you want.

```
myList:Array<any>=[{prop:someValue},{prop:someOtherValue}];
```

and then in the template, you can loop the list, and print your prop.

If you post your class, and try to explain in more detail what you want to do, it will be easier to help you.